# Replacing values in strings in Python using replace method doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the dataset from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/rajeevw/ufcdata with the data.csv file, and I tried to replace the values from Weight column using this code to later transform it to integer column, but I am already stuck at getting rid of the strings as follows:

```
fighter_data['Weight'] = fighter_data['Weight'].replace(" lbs.",'')
fighter_data
```

So an example will be: a value of  `145 lbs.` and I use the code above to get rid of lbs so that it can be integer 145. Apparently the code above doesn't work and nothing changes. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You could also use regex for this eh, it might be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `regex=False` and `str.replace`:

```
fighter_data['Weight'] = fighter_data['Weight'].str.replace(" lbs.",'', regex=False)
```

Or use `\\`:

```
fighter_data['Weight'] = fighter_data['Weight'].str.replace(" lbs\\.",'')
```

And add a `.astype(int)` at the end of the line if you want to convert to integer.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect! I have no idea we have to put .str in between :(

Comment: I can only do so two minutes after this, btw do you know how to get rid of  ' or " character? I tried to do so with the above .str.replace() but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user71812 `fighter_data['Height'] = fighter_data['Height'].astype(str).str.replace("'",'.').str.replace('"','').astype(float)`

Comment: Yay this works! Thanks a lot @U10-Forward for your great help! Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
fighter_data['Weight'] = fighter_data['Weight'].str.replace(" lbs.",'')
```